# Why is Android emulator asking for Flash Player to be installed when it is already installed?

Tags: android-emulator, flex4.5

I am trying to run a flex mobile application on the android emulator(2.3). The app. uses StageWebView to display a local HTML file. When run in android emulator, it asks for flash player to be downloaded. I have already installed Adobe AIR 3.0 and Flash Player 10.1 in my emulator. Why does it ask for a Flash Player to be installed??

Answer (score 1):

my guess is because its emulating. so either a. it needs flash installed in the emulator or b. it cannot access flash